# Why is the following relation not transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $A$ be $\{a,b,c\}$. Let the relation $R$ be $\{(a,a),(c,c),(a,b),(b,a)\}$.

Since $(a,b) \land (b,a) \to (a,a)$ this shows transitivity.
Furthermore $(c,c)$ doesn't have anything else it relates to so, therefore, you can assume the premises are false as well as the conclusion being false so, therefore, showing transitivity.

Comment: You are overlooking a failure of transitivity.

Comment: Does $(b,a) \wedge (a,b) → (b,b)$?

Comment: We have $(b,a)$ and $(a,b)$ but $(b,b)$ is missing.

Comment: But I don't understand why we need (b,b)

Comment: The two comments above you explain why.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot, I see what you're talking about. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A relation $R$ is transitive if whenever $xRy$ and $yRz$ we have $xRz$. We have $bRa$ and $aRb$ but not $bRb,$ i.e. transitivity fails when $x=z=b$ and $y=a$. Therefore transitivity fails for $R.$

Answer (score 3):

It seems the question has been answered in comments, but just to make sure it has an answer:

> A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is called **transitive** provided for all $x$, $y$, and $z$ in $A$, $x\mathrel Ry \wedge y\mathrel Rz \implies x\mathrel Rz$.

Let $x=b$, $y=a$, and $z=b$.  Then $x \mathrel{R} y$ and $y \mathrel{R} z$.  But $x \mathrel{R} z$ is equivalent to $b \mathrel{R} b$, which is not true.  So $R$ is not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

for transitivity, for all (a,b) and (b,c) belongs to the relation (a,c) should belong to the relation. This interpretation forces us to check (b,a) , (a,b) implies (b,b).